# datatable sAjaxSource htaccess

Tags: json, .htaccess, redirect, datatables

I use **htaccess** for my php application, now i want to use `datatable api` for get result from php file, my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var myTable=$('#resolus').dataTable( {
                        "bProcessing": true,
                                            "bServerSide": true,
                                            //"bFilter": false,
                        "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/framework/public/js/requete_admin_resolus.php",
                                            "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                                                    aoData.push({"name":"critere","value":$("select[name='choix'] option:selected").val()});
                                            },
                                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                                            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                                            "aoColumns": [
                                            null,
                                            null,
                                            null,
                                            null,
                                            {"bSortable": false },
                                            null,
                                            {"bSortable": false }
                                            ],
                                            "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                                                    $('#resolus tbody tr td').each(function(){
                                                            $(this).css('border','1px solid black');
                                                            $(this).css('text-align','center');
                                                            }),
                                                    $("#resolus tbody tr").hover(
                                                            function () {
                                                                    $(this).css("background-color","#F7951E");
                                                                    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
                                                            },
                                                            function () {
                                                                    $(this).css("background-color","white");
                                                                    $(this).css('cursor','auto');
                                                            }
                                                    );
                                                    $("#resolus tbody tr").click(function () {
           /* CLICK SUR UN ENREGISTREMENT */               mapopup("admin_detail.php?id="+$(this).find('td:first').text()+"&solution=1")
                                                    } );
                                                },
                                            "fnInitComplete":function() {
                                                    $(".dataTables_filter").wrap("<div id='rechercher'></div>");
                                                    $('<div style="float:left;padding-top:7px;background-color: #F7951E;"><b>Rechercher dans:</b><select id="choix" name="choix" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;"><option name="choix" value="id">Num Incident</option><option name="choix" value="date">Date</option><option name="choix" value="nom">Nom - Prénom</option><option name="choix" value="identifiant">Identifiant</option><option name="choix" value="pb">Problème</option></select></div>').insertBefore(".dataTables_filter");
                                                    $('<div class="clear"></div>').insertAfter("#rechercher");  
                                                    $('<input type="button" class="rech" value="OK" />').insertAfter(".dataTables_filter :text");
                                                    $('.rech').click(function(){
                                                    myTable.fnFilter($('.dataTables_filter :text').val());    
                                                    });
                                                    $('.dataTables_filter :text')
                                                        .unbind('keypress keyup')
                                                        .bind('keypress', function(e){
                                                        if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
                                                        myTable.fnFilter($(this).val());
                                                        });
                                                    },
                                                    "oLanguage": { 
                                                    "sProcessing":   "Traitement en cours...",
                                                    "sLengthMenu":   "Nombre de lignes par page: _MENU_",
                                                    //"sLengthMenu":   "",
                                                    "sZeroRecords":  "Aucun élément à afficher",
                                                    //"sInfo": "Affichage de l'�lement _START_ � _END_ sur _TOTAL_ �l�ments",
                                                    "sInfo": "",
                                                    //"sInfo": "",
                                                    //"sInfoEmpty": "Affichage de l'�lement 0 � 0 sur 0 �l�ments",
                                                    "sInfoEmpty": "",
                                                    //"sInfoFiltered": "(filtr� de _MAX_ �l�ments au total)",
                                                    "sInfoFiltered": "",
                                                    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
                                                    "sSearch":       "",
                                                    "sUrl":          "",
                                                    "oPaginate": {
                                                            "sFirst":    "<<",
                                                            "sPrevious": "< Précédent",
                                                            "sNext":     "Suivant >",
                                                            "sLast":     ">>"
                                                        }
                                                            }
                    } );
                } );
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
    <TABLE class='table table-striped table-bordered' width="100%" id="resolus">
                                        <thead>
                        <TR>
                                                    <TH>Num incident</TH>
                                                    <TH>Date création</TH>
                                                    <TH>Nom Prénom</TH>
                                                    <TH>Identifiants</TH>
                                                    <TH>Télephone</TH>
                                                    <TH>Description problème</TH>
                                                    <TH>Dernier dépannage</TH>
                        </TR>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty">Chargement des données...</td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                    </TABLE>    
- a result of requete_admin_resolus.php is echo json_encode( $output );
- my htaccess in public folder:(i have another htaccess file in main folder but it redirect file to htacces of public folder)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

[this url](http://localhost/framework/public/js/requete_admin_resolus.php)  **doesn't work**, if i try to do that `without htaccess` it work even with this url, absolute url or relative url. i think that it's a problem about `htaccess` and `json` result. sorry for my english.
thank for all.

Comment: What's the error message? what is the content of the .htaccess file?

Comment: hi Sebastianb, look at my response

Answer (score 0):

my .htaccess file in main folder:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/img/upload/photos/* [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

my .htaccess file in public folder:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

there is no error. this work it work perfectly, but with .htaccess it dos'nt work